# Don't store lastOpened in a SoapUI project

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I have a SoapUI project that is maintained by multiple developers and stored in SVN. In the project file `settings.xml` there is a property `lastOpened` which shows the datetime at which the project was opened last. This is a source of SVN conflicts.

Is it possible to stop SoapUI (we use it through ReadyAPI) from storing this field?

```
Projectdir
|- reports // dir
|- testsuites // multiple dirs
|- settings.xml // <-- this one.
```

Comment: which one are you referring when you mention `settings.xml`? And what exactly causing the problem? I do not happen to find `lastOpened` in either soapui project, or soapui-settings.xml or workspace xml. I have my project in svn too.